# Bitcoin-Qt source code walkthrough

Tags: bitcoin-core

Has there been content published which provides an overview of how the Bitcoin-Qt software is architected?

I would like to dive into the source code, but going from scratch is somewhat taxing. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=41718.0
Don't miss the threads it links to at the bottom of the post.

But I wouldn't recommend diving right in if you don't know the basics of how bitcoin functions. You are going to need an okay understanding of cryptography used and C++, networking and program design.